# Making an HTTPS SVN command-line request with exec() in PHP

Tags: php, apache, svn, plesk

I've got a command I've created that makes an info call to an SVN repository stored on hosted SVN service. Here's an example:

```
exec('svn info https://myrepo.svn.beanstalkapp.com/project/name/folder 2>&1', $output, $returnStatus);
if ($returnStatus)
{
    print_r($output);
}
```

The response I get is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Authentication realm:  SVN
    [1] => Password for 'apache': Authentication realm:  SVN
    [2] => Username: svn: PROPFIND request failed on '/project/name/folder'
    [3] => svn: PROPFIND of '/project/name/folder': authorization failed (https://myrepo.svn.beanstalkapp.com)
)
```

I'm running the script on a box that has Plesk on it. It runs final locally so I suspect it's a configuration issue (which I can't seem to find any answers for online).

I don't know how to make the apache user be able to access the authentication realm - I believes that's the issue at hand.

Comment: It seems to use basic auth over https. So it might be sufficient to use `svn --password ... --username ...` for running the request.

Comment: I still throws that error. The exact command I'm using is svn info --username myuser --password pass https://myrepo.svn.beanstalkapp.com/project/name/folder 2>&1 - gives the same error. :-(

Comment: Can you also add `--no-auth-cache --non-interactive` options for testing? That might be relevant in your case. Otherwise try to set $HOME and $USER to the account you successfully executed `svn info` with. Or as last resort configure `sudo` to perform any interaction under that account - instead of the `apache` user (might run in a sandbox/jail/selinux/etc?).

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the login credentials - `--username` and `--password` ( or make sure that the credentials are stored in ~/.subversion for the user running the app)

And why don't you use some client library like phpsvnclient - http://code.google.com/p/phpsvnclient/

Comment: I would use the phpsvnclient, but it isn't very friendly or doesn't seem well supported. I was actually passing in the username and password via the URL ie. http://username:password@http://myrepourl.beanstalkapp.com - it still throw that error...I think it's a configuration error or something...maybe the Apache user doesn't have permission to access that "realm"?

Comment: David D. - Did you try it as `svn info --username <username> --password <password> https://myrepo.svn.beanstalkapp.com/project/name/folder`